# Webserver httpd.conf file rewriterules not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, webserver, httpd.conf

I have deployed my application on Websphere application server and my appserver and webserver communicates with each other.

I have deployed one application with /toms context root and other application with /tomsmt context root. Now i changed my rewrite rule in httpd.conf to run both the application. But the application runs on /toms context root but when i run the application deployed by /tomsmt context root then i get error.

Can someone please help.

My rewrite rule is as follows

RewriteRule ^/(toms |tomsmt)$ (toms |tomsmt)/backend/index.cfm [R]

now URL/toms/backend/index.cfm works but URL/tomsmt/backend/index.cfm does not work

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have to reach your backend, which you do not specify and could affect this.

You need to referenced the value captured with parentheses not trying to capture it in a the destination url

As in:

```
RewriteRule ^/(toms |tomsmt)$ /$1/backend/index.cfm [R]
```

$1 references the captured group: (toms  OR tomsmt) and will use whichever value as it was requested by the client and use it to make the redirection.

There is another way, using RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(toms |tomsmt)$ /$1/backend/index.cfm
```

**SideNotes:**
In your RewriteRule you do not use the flag L, consider the rewriting won't stop if there are further rewriterules down bellow, beware of rewrite loops.

As in the example above, I prefer to use mod_alias Redirect/RedirectMatch for simple external redirections, they get the job done and are not overkill for such simple redirections. It is wise to not use mod_rewrite unless you really have to.